# Azure AD integrations with own PHP platform

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have a organization in Microsoft Azure AD. I want to check via php if user password that would be filled by the form is the same in Azure. Can I make it without app and SSO? Is something similar to LDAP to make it work? I see something like Pass-through but I cannot find the example to use it.